# How to create a unordered list from mysql database using php

Tags: php, html

I done a code for displaying unordered list like this. But it's not working correctly how do i make correctly.i am new to php please help me thanks in advance.

```
        <ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>A</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>A1</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>A3</li>
            </ul>
            <ul></ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>A2</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>A4</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <ul>
                <li class='chlnode'>A5</li>
              </ul>
              <ul></ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>B</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>B1</li>
            <li class='chlnode'>B2</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>B3</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <ul>
                <li class='chlnode'>B4</li>
              </ul>
              <ul></ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>C</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>C1</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>C2</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <ul>
                <li class='chlnode'>C3</li>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <ul>
                  <li class='chlnode'>C4</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                  <ul>
                    <li class='chlnode'>C5</li>
                  </ul>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>D</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>D1</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>D4</li>
            </ul>
            <ul></ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>D3</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>D5</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <ul>
                <li class='chlnode'>D6</li>
              </ul>
              <ul>
                <ul>
                  <li class='chlnode'>D7</li>
                </ul>
                <ul></ul>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>E</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>E1</li>
          </ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>F</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>F1</li>
          </ul>
          <li class='mainnode'>G</li>
          <ul>
            <li class='chlnode'>J</li>
            <ul>
              <li class='chlnode'>J1</li>
            </ul>
            <ul></ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
```

this is my php function for creating  html code.

```
<?php
function menu()
{
    echo "<ul>";
    //this is sql query for parent element
    $list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE col2='0' ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
        echo "<li class='mainnode'>" . $row['col3'] . "</li>";

        echo "<ul>";
        //this is sql query for child element    
        $list1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE `col2`= " . $row['col1']);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list1)) {
            echo "<li class='chlnode'>" . $row['col3'] . "</li>";

            $list2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE `col2`= " . $row['col1']);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list2)) {
                echo "<ul>" . "<li class='chlnode'>" . $row['col3'] . "</li>" . "</ul>";

                echo "<ul>";
                $list3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE `col2`=" . $row['col1']);
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list3)) {
                    echo "<ul>" . "<li class='chlnode'>" . $row['col3'] . "</li>" . "</ul>";

                    echo "<ul>";
                    $list4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE `col2`= " . $row['col1']);

                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list4)) {

                        echo "<ul>" . "<li class='chlnode'>" . $row['col3'] . "</li>" . "</ul>";


                        echo "<ul>";
                        $list5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE `col2`= " . $row['col1']);

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list5)) {

                            echo "<ul>" . "<li class='chlnode'>" . $row['col3'] . "</li>" . "</ul>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You have not yet received a professional grade answer.  I would encourage you to lift your green tick until you do.  You will have a higher chance of receiving high quality answers if you provide the structure of your database table and enough rows to represent what you are trying to achieve.  Then, based on the data in the rows, show us how the finished html should look.  By doing all of these things, your question will gain clarity, the answers can be more accurate, and SO's content will greatly improve.  Thank you in advance for doing the right thing.

Comment: Here is a hint regarding what to look for in a high quality answer: ONE SELECT QUERY IN TOTAL.  A good programmer will call one query, and iterate the single resultset to write the entire list.

Comment: Fixed code formatting issues

Answer (score -2, accepted):

first you need to take the count of the returning rows from mysql.
then put a for loop to iterate and print the list.inside the for loop you can put your while loop and print the list tags as you wish.

Comment: Is this answer green tick worthy?  I think not.

Comment: @Shivu provides code but you can't manage to in your answer?  Please improve this answer.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it is a remarkably poor quality answer  (nearly a comment).  I'm absolutely shocked that it was awarded the green tick.   ...but new users make mistakes all the time.

Comment: This is my downvote.  I am downvoting because this answer, in its current state, will be decidedly unhelpful to the great majority of future readers.  Remember, this page/site is not a single-use, interaction between the asker and you.  StackOverflow will serve its content to thousands of thousands of future readers/developers for years to come.  Posting two vague sentences and calling it a solution is down right shameful.  If you ever update your answer to be something of value, you may ping me and I will judge whether I feel it deserves the removal of my downvote (and perhaps an upvote).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `mysql_` Deprecated use `mysqli_` . Try to make Unordered list `<ul>` before while loop and try to loop every row value with `<li>`.

Here the Glimpse on it.

```
<?php $list1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM abc WHERE col2= ".$row['col1'] ); ?>
<ul>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list1)) { ?>
        <li><?php echo $row['col3']; ?>"</li>

    <?php  $list2  = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `abc` WHERE `col2`= ".$row['col1'] );  ?>
      <ul>
      <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list2)) 
        { ?>
           <li><?php echo $row['col3']; ?>"</li>
  <?php } ?>
      </ul>
   <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is for only one element. How to do more elements ?

Comment: @Shivu Updated answer. You can take this as a reference and you have to do it on your own.

Comment: Please never EVER advise anyone to use `mysql_` functions on StackOverflow.  Show them better coding practices.  We can influence developers to upgrade their functions by cringing everytime they post deprecated calls.

Comment: "Try this.." does  a very poor job of educating the OP and future readers.  Please explain what your method does and why it is an appropriate method.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for Correcting me. I just looked at the problem, but haven't looked at mysql syntax.

Answer (score -2):

All the nested ul should start within Li as follows.

```
<ul>
    <Li> c
      <ul>
         <Li> c1 
           <ul>
             <Li> c2 </Li>
           </ul>
         </Li>
      </ul>
     </Li>
  </ul>
```

Hope this will solve the display problem

Comment: <li class='mainnode'>C</li><ul><li class='chlnode'>C1</li><ul><li class='chlnode'>C2</li></ul><ul><ul><li class='chlnode'>C3</li> In my Code Its coming like this how can change this correct way.<ul>
    <Li> c
      <ul>
         <Li> c1 
           <ul>
             <Li> c2 </Li>
           </ul>
         </Li>
      </ul>
     </Li>
  </ul> like this